# Cannot Get StreamBuilder Data

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

I am trying to get the updated data from a stream but, even though I get data coming down in my future function, the snapshot.data give me this error:

```
type '_ControllerStream<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

Here is my function and stream:

```
Future getChat(orderId) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var _token = prefs.getString('token');
  print('The Latest Order Token is $_token');

  final Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    "id": "$orderId",
  };
  final List _messageData = [];

  var url = Uri.parse('$_server/api/driver/get/convo/?access_token=$_token');

  await http.post(url, body: body, headers: {
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }).then((http.Response response) {
    print(response.body);

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        print("The ${response.body}");

        var x = responseData['message_data'].split(",");

        print(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          _messageData.add(x[i]);
          print(x[i]);
        }
        print(x);

        break;
      default:
        final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        print(responseData);
        return _messageData;
    }
    return _messageData;
  });
}


Stream getChatData(Duration refreshTime, id) async* {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(refreshTime);
    yield getChat(id).asStream();
  }
}
```

I get this in the data response:

> "message_data": ""11-12-21:09:01:14AM - Billy Fakename: fire
> test,11-12-21:09:01:30AM - Test TEster: ewserasece,""

My stream builder is:

```
  Stream _chatStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _chatStream = getChatData(Duration(seconds: 3), orderid);

    super.initState();
  }

StreamBuilder(
                stream: _chatStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final messages = snapshot.data;
                    List<MessageBubble> messageWidgets = [];
                    for (var message in messages) {
                      final msgText = message;
                      final msgSender = message;
                      // final msgSenderEmail = message.data['senderemail'];
                      final currentUser = "loggedInUser.displayName";

                      // print('MSG'+msgSender + '  CURR'+currentUser);
                      final msgBubble = MessageBubble(
                          msgText: msgText,
                          msgSender: msgSender,
                          user: currentUser == msgSender);
                      messageWidgets.add(msgBubble);
                    }
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView(
                        reverse: true,
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
                        children: messageWidgets,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center();
                  }
                },
              ),
```

But, I get this error: type '_ControllerStream' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable' or the snapshot will be null.

How do I get the information that shows up in the future function, show up in the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us where you define *_chatStream* ?
Your StreamBuilder uses _chatStream but you only showed us where you define the method

```
Future getChat(orderId)
```

and the method

```
Stream getChatData(Duration refreshTime, id)
```

where you create a stream that you do not use in the code you've shared.
Did you want to use *getChatData* in your StreamBuilder?
Did I miss something?

Comment: It is updated in the init state. I updated the code to reflect it.